# Python Error: 'int' object has no attributes in dumps

Tags: python, json, attributes, attributeerror

I am getting the above error for the last two lines, and I am not sure what this error means.  I am trying to get the "pretty" print in the output.  Could someone please provide some insight about this error?  What have I missed?

```
import json
import urllib

serviceurl = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.json'

while True:
    url = serviceurl + urllib.urlencode({'sensor':'false', 'address': 'address'})
    print "Retrieving", url
    uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = uh.read()
    print "Retrieved", len(data), "characters"
    try:    js = json.loads(str(data))
    except:     js = None
    js = js["comments"][0]["count"]
    print js.dumps(js, indent = 4)
    print sum(js.get('count', 0) for js in js['comments'])
```

JSON data looks like this:

```
{
  comments: [
    {
      name: "Matthias"
      count: 97
    },
    {
      name: "Geomer"
      count: 97
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You assigned an integer to the variable `js` on the  line before:

```
js = js["comments"][0]["count"]
```

You can't then call `js.dumps()`, because `int` objects have no such method. Perhaps you wanted to call `json.dumps()` instead?

```
print json.dumps(js, indent = 4)
```

You'll have more problems however, as you replaced `js` with an `int` you also can't loop over it here:

```
print sum(js.get('count', 0) for js in js['comments'])
```

Perhaps you should use a *different* variable for the count; `count` would work, and `comment` in the loop:

```
count = js["comments"][0]["count"]
print json.dumps(js, indent = 4)
print sum(comment.get('count', 0) for comment in js['comments'])
```

Comment: Thank you.  This makes much better sense to me now.  I see how it is all matching up.